# Installing asp.net web app on new server

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, windows-installer, windows-server-2012-r2

I have an asp.net web application I have built using Visual Studio 2010 C# (.net 4.0). I deployed it successfully onto Windows Server 2003 with .net framework 4.0 installed on it.

I am now trying to deploy it on Windows Server 2012 R2 with .net framework 4.5 installed on it (I have to use 4.5 as another application on the machine requires it).

I am getting this error message during instillation:

```
Could not open key: Software\Microsoft\ASP.NET\4.0.30319.0. Verify that you have sufficient access to that key, or contact your support personnel.
```

I have read many posts that suggest I rebuild my application changing the 'ASPNETVersion' to 2.0 instead of 4.0.  This does not work however as .net framework 2.0 is not installed on the server and I encounter build issues when building on my dev machine with .net 4.0.

IIS Application pool is pointing NET CLR to 4.0. The version of .net in the server regedit file is `v4 (Client 4.5, Full 4.5), v4.0 (Client 4.0)`.

Is this possibly because v4.0 Client profile is installed rather than the full 4.0 .net install?  I have looked online and it doesn't look like full 4.0 .net can be installed on Windows Server 2012 R2?

Comment: The exception is talking about not having sufficient access to open a registry key. You need to make sure the user running your installer has sufficient access and the install process is running with elevated privilege.

Comment: Hi Kevin, running the installer by just double clicking it provides the message `You do not have sufficient privileges to complete this installation for all users of the machine`.  So I have opened a command prompt as Administrator and then run the installer from there which lets me click through and install until I get the original error message.  So I assume that I have sufficient access?

Comment: You may need to grant permissions to your user specifically to that registry key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrongly presumed that ASP.NET was part of the .NET framework installation.  I went back to the IIS install and installed ASP.NET which was listed under the development section.  The Installer now starts correctly.